# Blurry background-image on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, background-image

I have a `div` with properties and values of:

```
#main {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

And when i tested website on iPad,the image appeared to be blurry and centered incorrectly.What could cause that problem? Any solutions please

Comment: for the blurry part , did u wait for the image to load?

Comment: And u may want to check this out http://www.alaress.com.au/2011/04/developing-for-high-dpi-devices/

Comment: no,it stays blurry all the time